# Can I use many relative pronouns in one sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-pronouns, relative-clauses, coordination

I learned how to use one relative pronoun in a sentence.

Ex: The zoo **where you can find animals** is amazing.

Can I use two or more relative pronouns?

Ex: The zoo which is not expensive and where you can find animals is amazing.

If the previous sentence is correct and I need to add more relative pronounce. Do I have to repeat the word "And" ?

I'm not asking about the grammar point of view. I'm asking about how to sound like a native English speaker.

Comment: It sounds fine, but it's also like using **and**, you may use as many as you like, but after a while it sounds really long.

Comment: Sure.  The zoo, which has been there for more than a hundred years, and where many of the animals are rare and endangered today, has free admission on Sunday mornings.

Comment: "The zoo where you can find animals" is redundant as the definition of the word zoo is **an establishment which maintains a collection of wild animals**. There is no zoo where you can't find animals unless they went out of business.

Comment: @Rathony Oh, hahahaha nice notice. This is just an example. I used it to clarify what I mean because I can express this questions in pure English without using examples.

Comment: @TRomano This is a great comment. If it was an answer, I would give it the best answer.

Comment: I will do it now.

Comment: @TRomano sorry for late :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can.

> The zoo, *which* has been there for more than a hundred years, and *where*
>   many of the animals are rare and endangered today, has free admission
>   on Sunday mornings